# Check if a matrix is a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

Is 
$$ W=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 5  \\
-2 & 4 \\ \end{array} \right)$$

a linear combination of 
$$ A=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 2  \\
0 & 1 \\ \end{array} \right), B=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 2  \\
-2 & 4 \\ \end{array} \right), C=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1  \\
-2 & 5 \\ \end{array} \right)?
$$
**What I've tried**:

The idea is clear,

$$W=c_1A+c_2B+c_3C$$

should have a solution. However, when trying to solve these I get no structure and it gets to a more "heavier" solution than I expect it to be. The primary thing I've tried is to check that every column is fulfilled which gives my two equation systems, but as I wrote, I cannot see the general way - the solution gets ugly.

Am I on the right way?

Comment: Convert the matrices to 4x1 column vectors, then attempt to use Guassian elimination.

Comment: This is the correct idea. Note that you want to say is $W$ a linear combination of $A,B,C$ not the other way around. Also, $W = A - C + 2B$ (I got this just by inspection)

Comment: what about $A+2B-C$

Comment: @DavidPeterson: How do I succeed converting to column vectors?

Comment: @Deven Ware: Yeah, I saw that now. However, I do not want to do it by inspection (it's a good idea when one is used to calculate these things), but for now I think I will go with David's approach. Thanks anyway.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto  (a,b,c,d)^T$

Comment: @JulianAssange Indeed, inspection is a bad idea in general, especially in the case where $W$ is not a linear combination of the other three. This is why I was simply commenting, rather than posting an answer!

Comment: @JoseAntonio: How does that follow to $(a,b,c,d)^T$?

Comment: The map $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto [A]= (a,b,c,d)^T$ is an isomorphism, so you have $c_1\cdot A+c_2\cdot B+c_3\cdot C \mapsto c_1\cdot [A]+c_2\cdot [B]+c_3\cdot [C]$ and you know how to solve $c_1\cdot [A]+c_2\cdot [B]+c_3\cdot [C]$

Comment: @JoseAntonio: I don't think we have been going through what a 'map' or an 'isomorphism' are, it sounds unfamiliar to me.

Comment: However, it seems pretty obvious that it is so when I look at @AnonSubmitter85's answer below.

Comment: Let $\rho: M_{2\times2}(R)\rightarrow R^4$, define as $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto [A]$ where $[A]= \begin{pmatrix}
   a \\
  b \\
 c\\ d \\
 \end{pmatrix}$, 

You need to know if  $W=\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 5 \\
   -2 & 4 \\
 \end{pmatrix} $ is a linear combination of $A,B,C$, well this happens $\iff W= c_1 A+c_2B+c_3C$, well since $W\mapsto [W]$, $W$ is a LC iff $[W]=c_1 [A]+c_2[B]+c_3[C]$ (because $\rho$ is a Linear transformation) and here proceeds as the solution of Anon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose any element in $\mathbf{W}$, we want to see if it is a linear combination of the corresponding elements of $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, and $\mathbf{C}$. For example, $w_{0,0} = c_1 a_{0,0} + c_2 b_{0,0} + c_3 c_{0,0}$. We can do this for all four elements in $\mathbf{W}$, which gives us the following systems of linear equations:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & -2 \\
1 & 4 & 5
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
2 \\ 5 \\ -2 \\ 4
\end{array}
\right].
$$

Note that the above is simply

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{0,0} & b_{0,0} & c_{0,0} \\
a_{0,1} & b_{0,1} & c_{0,1} \\
a_{1,0} & b_{1,0} & c_{1,0} \\
a_{1,1} & b_{1,1} & c_{1,1}
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
w_{0,0} \\ w_{0,1} \\ w_{1,0} \\ w_{1,1}
\end{array}
\right].
$$

If $\mathbf{W}$ is a linear combination, then the above system will have a solution. Otherwise, $\mathbf{W}$ is not a linear combination of $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{B}$, and $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up.

Comment: @JulianAssange You're welcome.